Uncertainty Propagation in Linear Systems
Suppose we have a linear dynamical system, written in discrete form as $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$, with $x_\cdot \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ a constant matrix. Now suppose that we are not certain about $A$. Rather, we have $A + \Delta A$, where $\Delta A$ is randomly selected from a distribution with zero mean and a nonzero covariance. Each value of $\Delta A$ would lead to a specific trajectory (Note that $\Delta A$ does not depend on time, so each one fixed for one trajectory). So the question is, starting from the same $x_0$, How do the mean and the covariance of $x$ propagate in time?
For the mean, we have:
$$
E[x_{k+1}] = E[(A + \Delta A) x_k] = AE[x_k] + E[\Delta A x_k]
$$
I immediately face a challenge here because $\Delta A$ and $x_k$ do not seem to be independent from each other (each $\Delta A$ leads to one and only one trajectory $x_k$).
Note that if we did not have uncertainty in $A$, things would have been easier: $E[x_{k+1}] = A E[x_k]$ and $\mathrm{cov}(x_{k+1}) = A \mathrm{cov}(x_{k}) A^\top$.
Edit 1. Since we have $x_k = (A + \Delta A)^k x_0$, we might be able to calculate $E[x_{k+1}]$ based on $E[\Delta A^k]$. But for covariance, we will face a term $E[\Delta A^k x_0 x_0^\top {\Delta A^k}^\top]$ which I don't know how to simplify.

$\Delta A$ is fixed at the begining or changes every step $k$?

@NN2 It is fixed, that is why I did not put subscript $k$ for it.

If $\Delta A$ is fixed (at the time $t = 0$), it is known and so considered constant for $k \color{red}{\ge 1}$. Then the sequence $(x_k)_k$ is deterministic in function of $A $ and $\Delta A$

@NN2 It is fixed at $t = 0$, but it is sampled from a random distribution. so each sample will lead to a different dynamics, leading to a different trajectory $x_k$. Therefore, we will have a distribution of trajectories, and the question is what is the first and second moments of those trajectories at time $k$.

Therefore, for every $k$, we have the closed form formula of $x_k$
$$x_{k} = \underbrace{(A+\Delta A(\omega))^k}_{\text{random}} x_0$$
And the problem is to compute the expectation of
$$\mathbb{E}(x_k) =  \mathbb{E}((A+\Delta A)^k) \cdot x_0$$
$$\mathbb{E}(x_k^2) =  x_0^T\cdot \mathbb{E}(((A+\Delta A)^k)^T\cdot (A+\Delta A)^k)\cdot x_0$$
which is doable if we know the distribution of $\Delta A$

The last line is not correct. It should be
$$
\mathbb{E}[(A + \Delta A)^k x_0 x_0^T{(A + \Delta A)^k}^\top]
$$

If you denote $B = (A+\Delta A)^k$, then for you should have
$$\mathbb{E}[x_kx_k^T]_{ij} =x_0^T \mathbb{E}[B_iB_j^T] x_0$$
